# Change font for string with object in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, fonts

I am bringing in some data from a `JSON` file and I want to change the font to `courier` but when I try to do the following I get this error: `"Property 'font' not found on object NSString"`. Is there any way around this?

```
NSString *timePeriod = [diction objectForKey:@"Time Period"];  

UIFont *changeFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:12];
timePeriod.font = changeFont;
```

Comment: You can try NSAttributedString

Answer (score 2):

A font is part of an attributed string.

```
NSMutableAttributedString timeSringWithAttr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:timeString];
[timeStringWithAttr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                           value:changeFont
                           range:NSRangeFromString(timeString)];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSString just stores strings, it has no knowledge of fonts.  If you want to set the font when you draw the string use the NSString AppKit additions:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000155

Basically, you want to set the font when you draw the string to screen.

Comment: Is there a way to set my table that this data is eventually going out to -- to a set font in storyboard mode? That would make my life a whole lot easier.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know storyboard mode really well, but if you're putting the string in a UILabel or UITextField, you can set the font of that UI element.  The string will pick up the font when drawn on screen.

Answer (score 0):

The NSString class doesn't have font property, and it shouldn't since every String object is an array of characters.
Instead, use UILabel or UITextView, depends on your needs with text in it, and set font property on them.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)];
label.text = @"YOUR_TEXT";
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:12.0f];
```

And in convention you shouldn't name variables with verb names, those are for functions.
Like UIFont *changeFont..